# Sentence ending でな

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles, role-language

> レモン・キャンディーじゃよ。マグルの食べる甘いものじゃが、わしゃ、これが好き**でな**。
>   A lemon sweet. It's a sweet thing that muggles eat. I like this ???

I understand the concept of role language for portraying different kinds of character. The speaker (professor Dumbledore) is an old man so he ends sentences with じゃ instead of だ for example.
I'm assuming that the ending でな is something like this.

The English translation is "I'm rather fond of them" (actually "it's a muggle sweet I'm rather fond of"). So, I can't see what function でな is performing.

Maybe it's not role language. Maybe it's just すきだ->すきで implying an unfinished sentence, with the sentence ending particle な on the end (a particle I've never got to grips with). I can't see why the translator would do this though.

In either case I can't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This でな is indeed the te-form of だ, followed by な, a masculine sentence-final particle.

A sentence-end で [can have several different roles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60764/5010). Here, it may be a reason marker (i.e., explaining to someone why he has a sweet), in which case the combination of で + な roughly corresponds to "you know" in English. Or it may be a simple "continuation marker". As [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54376/5010) suggests, this is a common pattern in Japanese, and this use of て/で can make the sentence sound simply more natural.