# Grammar behind ending an utterance with 思って

Tags: grammar, て-form

I have been unable to identify the grammar point in the following sentence in bold.

> リンさんと一緒に行きたいと思**って**•••。

Is it the ている form? (If so, why is it shortened? Cannot find anything to it) Or is it something entirely else?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39018/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48946/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In informal conversation,

> 「リンさんと一緒{いっしょ}に行{い}きたいと思{おも}っ**て**•••。」

can mean at least **two very different things** if no further context is given.

1) As a reply to a why-question as in "Because ~~~".  This is a common usage of ending a sentence (hanging) with 「思って・・・」.

> "Because (I thought) I wanted to go with リン...."

2) As a hanging sentence with the whole main clause left unsaid.

> "Thinking I would rather go with リン, **I .....**"

By "hanging sentence", I am **not** referring to a type of death penalty.

Answer (score 2):

> リンさんと一緒に行きたいと思って•••。

My translation would be something along these lines.

> I think that I want to go with Mr/Mrs Rin...

Note that I chose the subject of the sentence as `I`, but in this particular case, since it isn't 100% clear, it could easily be applied to another subject (`he, she, Bill, etc.`).

Now for your question:

> Is it the ている form?

No, this is not the ～ている form that you have been taught.  This is simply base て construction, (which is still somewhat related).  In this case the construction is not imperative, but rather conjunctive.  From [this web page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Verbs/te_form), we get the following:

> The te-form is often thought of as the conjunctive form. This allows the combination of verbs, phrases, and sentences. The verb and/or phrase may even have a different meaning when it follows after the conjunctive.

You may ask, "Why cut off right there?"  Simply put, there is some sort of unspoken implication or understanding between the speaker and the listener.  For example, the part left unsaid could be, "`...but (someone) won't/wouldn't let me`," or it could also be, "`...and that is working/worked out great!`"  Notice that tense is not definite here.  It is unsaid, and therefore unknown.  The key to knowing what is left unsaid depends on the context of the conversation.  Since we only have the one sentence, what is left unsaid is anyone's guess.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but I think it's worth explicitly mentioning that without the rest of the sentence (after 思って) we also can't infer tense. Especially because your initial translation is "I think..." but your later examples are past tense.

Comment: Excellent point, I'll add that when I get the chance to sit down.